# Script task failed to generate files

Tags: ssis

I have used script task in ssis package to generate loads of excel files automatically every month.

Untill now script task worked fine but this month failed and when I did debug error showing at below

```
results = re.Render(format, deviceInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
```

How can I fix this?

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
  public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
  {

    #region VSTA generated code
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion


    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string ssrsReport;
        string destination;
        string monthName;
        string yyyy;
        string currentReportName;
        string currentReportShortName;
        string password;
        string filetype;
        string version;

        yyyy = (string)Dts.Variables["varYear"].Value;
        monthName = (string)Dts.Variables["varMonthName"].Value;
        filetype = (string)Dts.Variables["varFileType"].Value;
        version = (string)Dts.Variables["varVersion"].Value;

        // The SQL Task already ensures that these following five values are not null:
        currentReportShortName = (string)Dts.Variables["varRSParameter"].Value;
        currentReportName = (string)Dts.Variables["varRSReportName"].Value;
        password = (string)Dts.Variables["varRSPassword"].Value;
        destination = (string)Dts.Variables["varDestinationPath"].Value + "\\" + "Data - " + currentReportName + " " + monthName + " - " + yyyy + "." + filetype;
        ssrsReport = (string)Dts.Variables["varSSRSReport"].Value;

        try
        {
            CreateFolder((string)Dts.Variables["varDestinationPath"].Value);

            RenderReport(destination, ssrsReport, currentReportShortName, password, filetype, version);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            throw;
        }

    }


    private void RenderReport(string destinationFile, string ssrsReport, string agent, string password, string filetype, string version)
    {

        string historyID = null;
        string deviceInfo = null;
        string format = null;

        if (filetype == "xls")
        {
            format = "Excel"; //Can be XML, NULL, CSV, IMAGE, PDF, HTML4.0, HTML3.2, MHTML, EXCEL, and HTMLOWC
        }
        else if (filetype == "pdf")
        {
            format = "PDF";
        }

        Byte[] results;
        string encoding = String.Empty;
        string mimeType = String.Empty;
        string extension = String.Empty;

        ReportExecutionService.Warning[] warnings = null;
        string[] streamIDs = null;

        ReportExecutionService.ReportExecutionService re = new ReportExecutionService.ReportExecutionService();
        re.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        re.Timeout = 600000;

        try
        {
            ReportExecutionService.ExecutionInfo ei = re.LoadReport(ssrsReport, historyID);

            // If we need to generate a parametised report then do that here:
            // check if multiple agent parameters are being passed for this report
            ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue[] rptParameters = new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue[4];

            rptParameters[0] = new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue();
            rptParameters[0].Name = "DataName";
            rptParameters[0].Value = agent;

            rptParameters[1] = new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue();
            rptParameters[1].Name = "Year";
            rptParameters[1].Value = (string)Dts.Variables["varYear"].Value;

            rptParameters[2] = new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue();
            rptParameters[2].Name = "Month";
            rptParameters[2].Value = (string)Dts.Variables["varMonth"].Value;

            rptParameters[3] = new ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue();
            rptParameters[3].Name = "version";
            rptParameters[3].Value = (string)Dts.Variables["varVersion"].Value; 

            re.SetExecutionParameters(rptParameters, "en-GB");

            results = re.Render(format, deviceInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

            FileStream stream = File.Create(destinationFile, results.Length);
            stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length);
            stream.Close();

            if (password != "NONE" && password.Length > 0)
            {
                PasswordProtectExcel(destinationFile, password);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error caught within RenderReport method: ", e);
        }
    }

    private void CreateFolder(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            bool exists = Directory.Exists((string)Dts.Variables["varDestinationPath"].Value);

            if (!exists)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory((string)Dts.Variables["varDestinationPath"].Value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error caught within CreateFolder method: ", e);
        }
    }

    // Code adapted from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/71222/
    private void PasswordProtectExcel(string excelSourceFile, string password)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = null;
        try
        {
            //open the Excel application
            excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelSourceFile, 0, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true,
                                                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", false, false,
                                                    0, false, false, false);
            //Save the file with the "excelSourceFile" name
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            excelWorkbook.SaveAs(excelSourceFile, Type.Missing, password, //password is used in the SaveAs function 
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, true, Type.Missing,
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error caught within PasswordProtectExcel method: ", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            //Close the workbook
            excelWorkbook.Close(true, excelSourceFile, false);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);
            excelWorkbook = null;
            //Quit the application
            excelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
            excelApp = null;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please can anyone suggest me

Comment: tried in google more and could not able to figure issue

Comment: Provide more code details. This is unclear

Comment: added the code in question. Is there anything wrong in code?

Comment: what is the error message received?

Comment: at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

Comment: at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: Above are the errors. How to fix these errors?

Comment: those are the error Stack trace not the error message. There are more details